# Are cantrips spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cantrips

There are a number of class features that provide benefits to 'spells'. For example, the Eldritch Knight's attacks can give an enemy disadvantage on saving throws from the EK's spells.

**Do cantrips count as spells for the purposes of such features?**

Obviously, in previous editions when cantrips were just 0-level spells, they would have. However, in 5e there is a level of differentiation between cantrips and spells.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

### Cantrips are spells.

> A cantrip is a spell ... A cantrip’s spell level is 0. (PHB, p. 201)

There are certain class features that require a spell, or a spell slot, of level 1 or above (The Life Cleric's Blessed Healer feature for instance) and as such cantrips would not qualify for these.  For all other spell casting features, they would qualify.