# Cantrips for each multi-class class?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, multi-classing

Would a Cleric 1 / Wizard 1 multi-classed character know 3 cleric cantrips *and* 3 wizard cantrips?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, you would know 3 Wizard cantrips and 3 Cleric cantrips. The Cleric class says:

> At level 1, you know three cantrips of your choice from the cleric spell list.

And the Wizard class says:

> At 1st level, you know three cantrips of your choice from the wizard spell list.

Finally, in the multiclassing section, we have:

> You determine what spells you know and can prepare for each class individually, as if you were a single-classed member of that class.

Cantrips are spells (see [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/47070/15469)), and are covered by this rule.