# Is Rakshasa immune to the Booming Blade cantrip?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters, cantrips

Is Rakshasa immune to the [*booming blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/booming-blade) cantrip (SCAG, p. 142)? Does it avoid also the extra damage?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## A Rakshasa is immune to the *booming blade* cantrip, unless they wish to be affected by it

The relevant trait of the [rakshasa](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/rakshasa) is as follows (emphasis mine)

> ***Limited Magic Immunity.*** The rakshasa can't be affected or detected by spells of 6th level or lower unless **it wishes to be**. It has advantage on saving throws against all other spells and magical effects. (*Monster Manual*, p. 257)

As *booming blade* is a cantrip, and [cantrips are spells](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47070/are-cantrips-spells) of sixth level or lower, the rakshasa can only be affected by the *booming blade* cantrip if it wishes to be, as indicated by the quote and emphasis above.

Answer (score 5):

### Yes. A Rakshasa's spell immunity includes cantrips

[Rakshasas](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/rakshasa) have the following trait:

> ***Limited Magic Immunity.*** The rakshasa can't be affected or detected by
> spells of 6th level or lower unless it wishes to be.  (*Monster Manual*, p. 257)

Cantrips are [spell level](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting#SpellLevel) zero, which is lower than 6.

> Cantrips—simple but powerful spells that characters can cast almost
> by rote—are level 0. (PHB, p. 202)

Comment: Seth, if you go ahead and select "edit" now, you can see what it looks like, now that the quote blocks have been added.